# Android Preparing MediaPlayer from method call ErrorListener

Tags: android

I have discovered today after digging in a lot of problems of `mediaPlayer` that preparing from an activity by calling a method to a object to stream a song from URL make `mediaPlayer` to action `onErrorListener`

I have an activity with `RecyclerView` and when I click on a position I call this method:

```
  musicController.playSong(position);
```

Now `musicController` is my object where I use `MediaPlayer` and have some `buttons` to action `previous/next/seekbar`.

The `playSong` method:

public void playSong(int position) {

```
    this.currentPosition = position;

    try {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicUrl.get(position));
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The ideea is that I tryed 2 types of `errorListener's`:

1)

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

            Log.i("TEST", "Error");
            playSong(currentPosition);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

2)

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                Log.i("TEST", "Error");

                  try {
                      mediaPlayer.stop();
                      mediaPlayer.reset();
                      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicUrl.get(currentPosition));
                      mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

The first one will loop without stopping in `logCat` and the second one will trigger only 1 time.What is the difference between them ? Also, I have read that `mediaPlayer` need a `Service` to play on background but I don't really understand if really needs because my music still plays when I go to home screen.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop music whenever

Home button pressed then u must want to override

**onPause()** for pause the music

and

resume the music u want **onResume()**

Comment: I don't want to do this, I wanna know why ErrorListener is looping with the method and why is not in the second case.

Comment: don't understand what u say ??

Comment: I prepare a mediaPlay by calling a method, when I do this he triggers onErrorListener and I made the ErrorListener to retry preparing the mediaPlayer again, if I make the errorlistener trigger again the method it loops and it doesn't stop. If I try to prepare the mediaPlayer inside the listener it works.